# Sitecore 6.5 urls across multiple sites/domains (not resolving sites?)

Tags: web-config, hyperlink, sitecore

I'm using a Sitecore install with multiple sites. When linking from example1.com (/sitecore/content/example1) to an item under example2.com (/sitecore/content/example2/about)

Sitecore is not generating the link correctly for any cross-domain links. It is generating:
http://www.example1.com/example2/about.aspx
This is what is expected:
http://www.example2.com/about.aspx

The same thing happens from example2.com when linking to example1.com or any item under that site.

- Both sites are defined in the web.config.
- The rootNodes are both "/sitecore/content"
- The start items are "/example1" and "/example2" respectively.
- Rendering.SiteResolving is set to true
- Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite is set to false
- I'm using sc:link to generate the links.
- Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider's alwaysIncludeServerUrl is set to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using hostName with wild cards (eg. "www.example1.com|example1.com"), you need to set targetHostName="www.example1.com" on your  entry.

Even if you only have one domain, set targetHostName, as there is one thing/function that only looks at targetHostName. Eg. GetItemUrl() doesn't work as planned without a targetHostName and in 6.5.0 ver. 120706 it doesn't account for stuff set in the web.config. This is a bug and one they hopefully have fixed in future version. If you expirience the problem look here for a solution:
http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/using-cross-site-links-dynamic-links/

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the hostName value of the <site> entry in web.config?

```
<site name="example1" hostName="www.example1.com" ... />
<site name="example2" hostName="www.example2.com" ... />
```

There's a very good blog post on this here: http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2011/05/01/sitecore-linkmanager-inside-out-muti-site-and-sub-site-setups/  It looks like you've covered everything else required to make this work.